# pymemcache unicode char issue

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, memcached

I am trying to save the value in Memcache but facing below error for value (for ñ in canada)

"last_name":"Cañada Herrador","personal_space_id":105175

> pymemcache.exceptions.MemcacheIllegalInputError: Data values must be binary-safe: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf1' in position 61: ordinal not in range(128)

How can I save Unicode characters in memcache, as by default it only supports ASCII char?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I save Unicode characters in memcache, as by default it only supports ASCII char?

You might harness [base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) built-in module for this task, but beware that if used with ASCII-only text it will take more space than text itself, consider following example:

```
import base64
last_name = "Cañada Herrador"
encoded_last_name = base64.b64encode(last_name.encode("utf-8")).decode("ascii")
# now encoded_last_name is ASCII str which you can use with memcache
print(encoded_last_name)  # Q2HDsWFkYSBIZXJyYWRvcg==
# after retrieving to get original string do
decoded_last_name = base64.b64decode(encoded_last_name).decode("utf-8")
print(decoded_last_name)  # Cañada Herrador
```

Comment: `response=[{"metadata":{"id":"ea69c6c5-2470-46af-b11d-bc428b93","resourceType":"user"}}]` in case if we have list of objects how we can encode this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.encode()` function, but you have to decide how to deal with unicode characters. Here https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#converting-to-bytes, you have all the options and explanations.